# What is the array type [J in java

Tags: java, arrays

We are well familiar with the standard primitive array types, e.g:

```
[I // array of integer
[L // array of Long
[D // array of Double
[Ljava.lang.Object   // array of Object
```

But what is

```
[J
```

Cluster assignments:  = 2 -> [J@4fe42c88,1 -> [J@d27bdb2,0 -> [J@2c16f7dd

**UPDATE**  So I had misread the output for [L : that is for a Class/Interface - I had thought it were for a long. Instead J is for the Long (as shown in the first answer)

Comment: Well, you shouldn't cut the output/result. `[Ljava.lang.Object` should indicate that `[L` is not the whole output for an `Long` array. In fact the correct one is `[Ljava.lang.Long`. And mind that `[D` is the encoding for a `double` array and not a `Double` array (`Double` is the wrapper type of `double`).

Comment: @Tom Actually, the correct one is `[Ljava.lang.Long;` -- the semicolon is required to terminate the internal name of the class. It's also missing after `Ljava.lang.Object;` in the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName())

```
Element Type        Encoding
long                J
...
```

i.e. its an array of long primitives

Comment: Thanks - where did you find that? Ah! you updated your answer already ;)